# Drag and Drop - storing drag positions in database

Tags: jquery

Is there any JQuery Plugin available for dragging and dropping the Image to Table layout and save the table div position to the DB?

I am having a webpage where I have couple of Images in left and right sides. I would like to configure it using JQuery Drag and Drop method. I mean I should have a JQuery plugin where I drag and drop Images to left and right side of webpage and this position will be saved to DB so that when user logs in they can see the images in configured positions.

This is for configuring the Image positions in webpage.

Note: I do not want database scripts. I already have a method "SavePositionToDB(string ImagePath, int tableRow,int TableColumn)"

JQuery event should call this method, thats it.

Thanks in advance
Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

analyse the given link, also with the example and you will find what you want,

but you have to do some extra stuff to after getting positions coordinates that is to pass that coordinates to Database via ajax request..

here is the link [draggable and droppable](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/)

hope this will help you